# How to Get Jump Boost Boots In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've made a parkour/adventure map based on popular video games, and I've included a Sonic the Hedgehog episode. For this map to be realistic, I wanted to be able to have a big jump boost. I've seen jump boost BOOTS, but all YouTube has on it are super complicated commands, and I was wondering if maybe someone would be kind enough to give me a relatively simple command or recipe that I could use (I could use potions but that wouldn't look to great).

Comment: Well, I think you won't get rid of complicated commands unless you would want to use Forge MOD for it. Because in vanilla MC you just need to have some CB that checks if you have boots on and then gives you the potion effect. Don't have proper time for answer, so just leaving comment here ^^

Comment: The only reasonable way to do this in vanilla is to use those supper complicated commands.  There are two common approaches, but I don't know all the commands off by heart.  I'll see if I can get an answer together for you though.

Answer (score 1):

As Antoine and MBraedley stated in the comments, you will need these more or less complicated commands to make jump boost boots work without a mod.

First of all, we'll need to determine if the player is wearing some special boots and store this in a scoreboard objective. To create the objective, run

```
/scoreboard objectives add jumpBoots dummy
```

once. Now, create a 20Hz. clock (fill clock or use repeat/chain command blocks in 1.9) and put the following two commands

```
/scoreboard players set @a[score_jumpBoots_min=1] jumpBoots 0
/scoreboard players set @a jumpBoots 1 {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:diamond_boots,Slot:100b,tag:{display:{Name:"Jump Boots"}}}]}
```

This will set the score to 1 for every player wearing Diamond Boots (i.e. they are in slot #100) named "Jump Boots", and 0 for everyone else. You can modify the data tag of the boots to suit your needs, e.g. change it to leather boots or change the name.

On the same clock, you can then put

```
/effect @a[score_jumpBoots_min=1] minecraft:jump_boost 1 <amplifier> true
```

Which will give the wearer of the boots 1 second of Jump Boost every tick. Replace `<amplifier>` with the level of jump boost you want to give minus 1, e.g. 2 for Jump Boost III. The `true` at the end hides the swirly particle effects, you can remove it if you want.

Comment: I could have sworn you could add potion effects to an item using the attributes system, but I'm not seeing anything relevant in my searches.  I may have to revisit that later.

Comment: @MBraedley might be possible, I never took the time to understand Attributes. Thanks for the command fixes, btw.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to get a jump boost in vanilla (normal/without mods) minecraft, I suggest you make a beacon (if you are in creative) and turn it on then right click and select jump boost, and then go into survival and walk through it, tada!
For the parkour, you could start with the players walking through a beacon, and then beginning the parkour, also make sure that you have a lot of gems surrounding it so the effect lasts longer.

(my apologies if this doesn't help)

Answer (score -2):

I have had to make jump boots before too, but the only way to do so that I have found is to put this super long command into a command block and add a button. It should give you them instantly. You can just copy and paste it into the command block.

```
give @p golden_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Jumping Boots",Lore:["gives you flying and jump boost and speed"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.maxHealth",Name:"generic.maxHealth",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:80901,UUIDLeast:98444},{AttributeName:"generic.followRange",Name:"generic.followRange",Amount:32,Operation:0,UUIDMost:13009,UUIDLeast:153291},{AttributeName:"generic.knockbackResistance",Name:"generic.knockbackResistance",Amount:20,Operation:0,UUIDMost:83502,UUIDLeast:718503},{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:19242,UUIDLeast:97406},{AttributeName:"generic.attackDamage",Name:"generic.attackDamage",Amount:5,Operation:0,UUIDMost:21041,UUIDLeast:883059}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:5},{id:2,lvl:6},{id:5,lvl:5},{id:6,lvl:1},{id:7,lvl:4},{id:8,lvl:3},{id:16,lvl:10},{id:19,lvl:10},{id:32,lvl:1000},{id:34,lvl:100}],HideFlags:5,Unbreakable:1}
```

Comment: It helps if you explain the command and why it works.  The command also does a bunch of things that wasn't asked for.